# Django displaying each object in a button

Tags: python, django

Good day, I have a page to test where tickets are created and where all created tickets (titles) are listed. Now you should be able to click on the title of a created ticket.

The button then redirects to an extra page where all the information of the specific ticket is.

I've always had trouble displaying user specific stuff, so what needs to be done so that the href="" of each link redirects in HTML to the specific ticket?

I did the following
\\forms.py

```
  {% for i in request.user.addtitle_set.all %}
  <div>
    {% if i.user == request.user %} {{ i.title }} {% endif %}
    <form action="{% url SOMETHING_HERE i.id}" style="display: inline">
      <button type="submit">View Ticket</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <br />
  {% endfor %}
```

\\urls.py

```
    path('dashboard/user/ticket', ticket_view),
    path('dashboard/user/ticket/<int:id>/',
         ticket_system_view, name="view_ticket"),
```

\\ models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        default=None,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    creator_adress = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

\\views.py

```
@login_required
def ticket_view(request, id, *args, **kwargs):

    try:
        obj = Ticket.objects.get(id=id)
    except Ticket.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TicketForm(request.POST, instance=Ticket(user=request.user))
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.creator_adress = get_client_ip(request)

            obj.save()
            return redirect('/dashboard/user/ticket')
    else:
        form = TicketForm()
    return render(request, 'ticket.html', {'form': form})


def ticket_system_view(request, id, *args, **kwargsw):
    # Here I will put all the stuff for the specific ticket page
    return render(request, 'ticket_system.html', {})
```

Edit:
I can not even access the page because of the error
TypeError at /dashboard/user/ticket

ticket_views() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Edit 2.0:
Solution:

```
    path('dashboard/user/ticket/', ticket_view),
    path('dashboard/user/ticket/<int:id>/',
         ticket_system_view, name="view_ticket"),
```

```
{% for i in request.user.ticket_set.all %}
<a href="{% url 'view_ticket' i.id %}"
  >{% if i.user == request.user %} {{ i.title }} {% endif %}</a
>
<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your urls.py

```
path('dashboard/user/ticket', ticket_view),
path('dashboard/user/ticket/<int:id>/',
         ticket_system_view, name="view_ticket"),
```

Should be

```
path('dashboard/user/ticket/<int:id>', ticket_view, name="some_name"),
path('dashboard/user/ticket/<int:id>/',
         ticket_system_view, name="view_ticket"),
```

As ticket_view expects an id

Comment: That would mean that I have to have some ID at the end of a URl in the ticket_view. But the ticket_view should only be a page where tickets are created and all tickets are displayed. The ticket_system_view is then used to display all the information for each individual ticket. So I would get the 404 Error because there is no ticket ID in the url when I just want to access dashboard/user/ticket/

Comment: Then remove "id" from  def ticket_view(.....)

Comment: Then what do I have to write in the href="" of the Link?

Comment: Just {% url 'some_name' %}

Comment: In your ticket_view you can display a list of tickets each line with a button/link to choose it. The button has a href={% url "detail_view_name" id=ticket.id %} that leads to detail page with id

Answer (score 0):

```
ticket_views() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

In your `views.py` you are getting argument id so it must be passed.
Change your `urls.py` as

```
path('dashboard/user/ticket/<int:pk>', ticket_view, name='ticket_view'),
path('dashboard/user/ticket/<int:id>/',
         ticket_system_view, name="view_ticket"),
```

Also your  `urlnamespace` in your form as

```
<form action="{% url 'ticket_view' i.id %}" style="display: inline">
```

There must be spaces before and after `%` in your url template tag. You were missing ending `%` add that too.